# How to clamp z rotation of a gameobject using touch input in unity without creating a jitter on y rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch-event, screen-rotation, clamp

I am able to clamp the z rotation of my game object using the code below, but it always changes the y rotation on my first touch. I only want to rotate the z-axis.

```
private float zRotation;

public void RotateMove()
{
    zRotation -= Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.y * rotateSpeed * invert * Time.deltaTime;
    
    // this limits the rotatioon
    zRotation = Mathf.Clamp(zRotation, -80, 80);
    //this rotates the game obj
    lamp2Rotate.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, zRotation);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sounds like `0` is not what you want for `Y`

You could instead keep the other two rotations:

```
var eulerAngles = lamp2Rotate.transform.eulerAngles;
eulerAngles.z = zRotation;
lamp2Rotate.transform.eulerAngles = eulerAngles;
```

Comment: Is there a way to prevent this from rotating on z axis on first touch before touchphase.moved. It moves imediately I touch the screen, but I want it to do that after touchphase.moved